# Cannot run 'scrapy crawl quotes'

Tags: python, scrapy

Cannot get scrapy tutorial to work.

Am trying to learn scrapy but can't get even the tutorial to run. I have tried to run this in python 3.7 & 3.5.5 with the same results

import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

```
def start_requests(self):
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

This appears to run OK. At least it throws no errors.

When I run "scrapy crawl quotes" in Anaconda prompt window, I get this:

```
"hed) C:\Users\userOne\python script files\scrapy\tutorial>scrapy crawl 
 quotes
 2019-01-23 18:34:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 
 tutorial)
 2019-01-23 18:34:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.3.0, libxml2 
 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 
 3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 24 2018, 01:52:17) [MSC 
 v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018), 
 cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 69, in load
     return self._spiders[spider_name]
 KeyError: 'quotes'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 
 10, in <module>
     sys.exit(execute())
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in execute
     _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 90, in _run_print_help
     func(*a, **kw)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 157, in _run_command
     cmd.run(args, opts)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
     self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 170, in crawl
     crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 198, in create_crawler
     return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 202, in _create_crawler
     spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
   File "C:\Users\userOne\Anaconda3\envs\hed\lib\site- packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
     raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
 KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'
```

"

The output should be similar to this:

```
"016-12-16 21:24:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> (referer: None)
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/> (referer: None)
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [quotes] DEBUG: Saved file quotes-1.html
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [quotes] DEBUG: Saved file quotes-2.html
2016-12-16 21:24:05 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)"
```

Thank in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Are you running `crawl` in the same dir as `scrapy.cfg`?

Comment: Yes, the config file is in the same directory.

Comment: Hi Jaaks, welcome to SO. Have you tried moving your scrapy project to a directory that does not contain spaces? It also _appears_ that scrapy thinks your spider is named `tutorial` -- you'll need to show us your Spider class in order to help you further

Comment: All this is from the scrapy documentation site: (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). I just copied & pasted. In the tutorial on the web site

Comment: import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

Comment: import scrapy class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider): name = "quotes" def start_requests(self): urls = [ 'quotes.toscrape.com/page/1', 'quotes.toscrape.com/page/2', ] for url in urls: yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse) def parse(self, response): page = response.url.split("/")[-2] filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page with open(filename, 'wb') as f: f.write(response.body) self.log('Saved file %s' % filename) – Jaaks just now   edit

Comment: Sorry. Don't seem to be able to format cot in a comment.

Comment: Sorry. Don't seem to be able to format code in a comment.

Comment: Run `scrapy list` to list the spiders detected.

Comment: YEP your quotes must be in spiders directory

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your source code has been placed in the wrong directory?

I had a very similar, if not the same, problem. (I am not using Anaconda, but the error was also "line 69, in load return self._spiders[spider_name] KeyError: 'quotes'".

What fixed it for me was moving the source code file (quotes_spider.py) from the projectname/tutorial/tutorial directory to the projectname/tutorial/tutorial/spiders directory.

From the tutorial page . . . 
"This is the code for our first Spider. Save it in a file named quotes_spider.py under the tutorial/spiders directory in your project"

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the answer. The tutorial doesn't mention one step that is only mentioned in your command line after you create the project via

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

The output for that command, besides creating your tutorial project, is

```
You can start your first spider with:
cd tutorial
scrapy genspider example example.com
```

For the tutorial to work, you need to enter

```
scrapy genspider quotes quotes.toscrape.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` is required and unique for every spider you create.

You can check this blog for getting started on Scrapy
https://www.inkoop.io/blog/web-scraping-using-python-and-scrapy/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name variable.

```py
def start_requests(self):
    name = "quotes"
    urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)`name = "quotes"
```